# Toggle display of divs 500ms apart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, webkit

What I want to do:

Using three divs occupying the same dimensions, all `display: none` by default;

1. load 2 images into second div
2. show first div for 500ms
3. show second div for 500ms
4. then show 3rd div.

Seem simple enough?

The weird thing is that like 15% of the time it's like it appears to wait on the first div and display it longer, then the second div will never be seen, appearing to go directly to the third div.

html:

```
<div id="div1">...</div>
<div id="div2"><div id="img1"></div><div id="img2"></div></div>
<div id="div3">...</div>
```

Attempt #1:

```
var focus_length = 500;
var stimuli_length = 500;

// dummy values
var newimg1 = 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png';
var newimg2 = 'https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png';


console.log("step 1");
$("#div1").show();
$("#img1, #img2").empty();
$("#img1").append($(document.createElement('img')).attr('src', newimg1));
$("#img2").append($(document.createElement('img')).attr('src', newimg2));

window.setTimeout(
    function () {
        console.log("step 2");
        $('#div1').hide();
        $('#div2').show();
    }, focus_length);

window.setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("step 3");
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').show();
}, focus_length + stimuli_length);
```

Second variant (same apparent behavior):

```
console.log("step 1");
$("#div1").show();
$("#img1, #img2").empty();
$("#img1").append($(document.createElement('img')).attr('src', newimg1));
$("#img2").append($(document.createElement('img')).attr('src', newimg2));

window.setTimeout(
    function () {
        console.log("step 2");
        $('#div1').hide();
        $('#div2').show();

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("step 3");
            $('#div2').hide();
            $('#div3').show();
        }, stimuli_length);
    }, focus_length);
```

I've also tried setting opacity=1 or 0 rather than using jquery show/hide, with the same result.

What's really weird is that even when experiencing this issue *the timings on the 3 console.log() messages are still 500ms apart!* So it's like it's like javascript is calling it correctly but the browser just doesn't bother to actually show the redraw. Even stranger this happens on both Chrome and Safari.

**update**

I tried setting `stimuli_length` to 1000 above. With this change it will sometimes appear to lag a bit on the first div and show the second div for a smaller amount of time, but does not appear to ever completely skip it. 500ms is a strict design requirement, however.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's something here with the dynamic appending of your images. Even if you show the div, if the images didn't have time to load, it will look exactly the same as if it was never shown.

Have you tried changing your delay for something like 10 seconds to be sure (or almost) that the images had time to load?

Comment: I've preloaded all of the images, so it shouldn't be an issue. I also tried something more complicated where I created an Image() object and put a handler on its load event that would only then trigger the next parts of the workflow; in that case the second div would sometimes show for like <100ms rather than not showing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `$("#div2, #div3").hide();` after you show the first div makes it work for me in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJRrx/6/).

Comment: div2 and div3 are already been hidden before any of this code executes

Comment: Yes I saw that later on. You are referring to the `display: none;` I suppose? But did the fiddle work for you?

Comment: Very strange why that works when you have `display: none;`. But I hope you find a solution that suits your needs!

Comment: How does the css for the divs look?

Comment: I used your css in the fiddle and removed my line. Still works. I don't know if can be browser specific? http://jsfiddle.net/cJRrx/8/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
('#div1').show(timeinmiliseconds);
```

It could solve your problem and also use callback for one after another
like

```
('#div1').show(timeinmiliseconds,('#div2').show(timeinmiliseconds, ('#div3').show(timeinmiliseconds);););
```